# Handle IDENTITY In Master/Detail Form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, identity

I have a master/details form for Staff and their Holidays using a BindingSource.

[image]

This is the code I currently have on the Save button, just to give a picture of how it is organized:

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    _bsStaff.EndEdit()
    _bsHoliday.EndEdit()
    If _dsStaff.HasChanges Then
        _daStaff.Update(_dsStaff.Tables("Staff"))
        _daHoliday.Update(_dsStaff.Tables("Holidays"))
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I handle the new identity value for a Staff member? That is, when a new Staff member is saved how can I get the details-form (Holidays) to pick-up the new StaffID value? According to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/09/15/inserting-master-detail-data-into-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database.aspx) I might make a trip to the database to retrieve the @@IDENTITY value (mine is with SQL Server Express) on the DataTable's RowUpdated event. That's fine, if it is necessary to do this, but I was under the (perhaps false) impression that this could all be handled within the DataSet. That is, I thought I could work with the data, eventually calling Update on the DataAdapter(s), and the next time I ran the application the IDs would appear.

(I suppose another option is, when a new staff-member is added, to re-fill the entire DataSet(?))

Also, a related question, is it necessary for me to Save/Update the new staff-member before I can add holiday details?

Answer (score 0):

In your insert command you can insert the new staff-member record and get the identity created for this record using `select scope_identity()`. These sql statements should be wraped up together in a stored procedure.

Then in your second insert you can use the value returen from the first insert.

Note: `@@identity` will give you the last identity value inserted anywhere in the database, this is why in your case you better use `scope_identity()` that will return the last identity inserted in the current session (i.e. in the stored procedure).

To answer your last question - yes, you must insert the master data before inserting the details data.